# JQuery check a checkbox then un-check/disable others with the same name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the three input checkboxes all of them have the same name attribute I want one of them is checked then others uncheck and disabled. I want to the jquery code within the function call on function and on change event like this code below or any another way work correctly.

```
<div class="topmenuitems">
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu-item-topitemtypes" value="itemwithouticon" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu-item-topitemtypes" value="itemwithicon" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu-item-topitemtypes" value="itemicon" />
</div>

var itemWithIconCheckbox = $('.topmenitems input');
var topItemTypesFunc = function() {
    //Jquery code here
};
topItemTypesFunc();
topItemTypeCheckboxes.on( 'change', topItemTypesFunc);
```

Comment: You know that this is what radio buttons are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the function you want via radio buttons. Here, I have implemented a simple logic here. When a checkbox is changed ten uncheck checkbox other then the clicked one. Here is an working example.

```js
$('input[name="menu-item-topitemtypes"]').on( 'change', function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
    $('input[name="menu-item-topitemtypes"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topmenuitems">
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu-item-topitemtypes" value="itemwithouticon" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu-item-topitemtypes" value="itemwithicon" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="menu-item-topitemtypes" value="itemicon" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help full to you

```
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).siblings().attr('disabled', 'true');
      }else{
        $(this).siblings().removeAttr('disabled', 'false');

      }
  })
```